# There is a new navigation topbar on the SO

Tags: discussion

...and so it looks:

[image]

Our good old black taskbar will probably go away.

Earlier the significant changes on the SO were later applied to the smaller SE sites as well (remember as the user pages were divided into two).

I suspect many can think, maybe the SE Inc made a lot, much better developments as well, compared to this change.

If you would like to remain at the current version, I would suggest to do every reasonable (incl. SE communication) to delay this unfortunate change...

Particularly for mods, they have access to the mod chatroom.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm bothered about this either way. What makes you dislike the new design so?

Comment: @Reaces It is disgusting, unergonomic, suboptimal. And it is fixed to the top (you will see it even if you scroll down).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Where? How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#fixedHeader

Comment: In addition, customisable tabs would be *ace*. *and* you can probably complain on MSO and let them be the guinea pigs so we get a significantly better experience.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks! So it is only worse, but not catastrophal. I think the idea is good, although I would start it from a different direction: I would list the most trivial and annoying longstanding problems (f.e.: https support on the meta sites) and then ask, how are these going if they have so many dev resources :-)

Comment: Different teams I suspect. One does not typically get a plumber to do electrical work. UX folk are a whole different beast from say SRE or backend development, who'd be the ones getting https working. And SE's pretty unique in how its laid out. Hundreds of subdomains and all that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek SNI exists since winvista+ie7... but there are other unexplained problems as well, although many of them are not SF-related, for example the lack of latex support on the chat and on many sites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SE will be doing this on the smaller sites eventually. And well, some of the issues people have with it feel feels a bit like

[image]
[source:xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

It also actually takes up *less* vertical space and uses horizontal space better (It dosen't use *more*, but moves things around a bit. Feels bigger to me)

[image]

And probably brings with it customisable tabs (and I will certainly be complaining loudly if we don't).

There's a bit of a learning curve (and when this hits SU, If the TPTB don't, I'll probably dig through and do a quick meta post on this - and if it hits here first, I might try it here first) but "disgusting, unergonomic, suboptimal. And it is fixed to the top" is 3/4 unclear and 1/4 wrong. If there's specifics you are unhappy with, go tell SE on MSO. We're pushing for a few things we need like [help links on the top bar for all users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343667/674571)

Now, I don't like the newfangled white theme, and some sites are going to be a agony in the donkey to do but this seems a bit hyperbolic.

Comment: This made my day :-)

Comment: You know what chance have such requests (I estimate around -15 on the meta SE + no responsible people will react), but I will try it. :-)

Comment: Gotta word it the right way. Try being less combative and clearer about *what* is wrong.

Comment: Why do we need links on the top bar that no one who needs to ever reads ?

Comment: That's a more specific complaint. Beats me, there's a whole blog post on that, and a meta post I posted saying the rest of us are left out on these changes ;p